# "No parameterless constructor defined for type 'System.Object[]'." for RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, restsharp

I am trying to deserialize a response object but I am getting this error

> "No parameterless constructor defined for type 'System.Object[]'."

This is where I am trying to serialiseObject to the request object and deserialise back to the response object

```
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fundTransferRequest), ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
IRestResponse<FundTransferResponse> res = client.Execute<FundTransferResponse>(request);
```

This is the response object

```
public class FundTransferResponse
{
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string TranStatus { get; set; }
    public string TranStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string SopraReference { get; set; }
    public string ReasonCode { get; set; }
    public object[] ReasonDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a `List<object>` instead?

Comment: Yes, It's working now. Thanks

Comment: Please delete this question, it is kind of an edge case with little value to others.

Comment: I don't think this is an "edge-case" situation. Defining an object to hold an array of objects isn't an edge case. It's typical class architecture and a good question.

Comment: It's not a RestSharp issue btw. We actually don't advise using RestSharp like this, you can use the serialiser instead.

Comment: Btw, you can just use `AddJsonBody(fundTransferRequest)` instead of adding the parameter manually.